# Replacing a line in Javascript

Tags: regex

I am a bit new to regular expressions. 
I have a line in an xml file which I want to replace with `null`. How can I do this?

```
<ns0:TradeMessage xmlns:ns0="http://aptp.accenture.com/BuySell">
      // Some More codes.
</ns0:TradeMessage>
```

Expected result -- Remove the `<ns0::>` tag complately to have `null`. Means my output should not have the first and the last line.

I have already tried using many regular expressions but I am unable to get the complete result

Comment: `string.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "")`

Comment: Hi Avinash thanks for the Reply But the thing is that my xml is something like this:   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><ns0:TradeMessage xmlns:ns0="http://aptp.accenture.com/BuySell">
   <SecuritiesTrade>
        <Direction>BUY</Direction></  SecuritiesTrade></ns0:TradeMessage>                                                   </ns0:TradeMessage>      so i now want to remove only the first and the last line. If i use your code all the '<' are getting removed :(

Answer (score 0):

The following example assigns your example XML to the JavaScript variable `string`. Then it uses a regexp to remove the `ns0:TradeMessage` tag. Of note, since there are `\n` new line characters, I used `[\S\s]*?` between the tags which will match any character including new lines.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var xml = '<ns0:TradeMessage xmlns:ns0="http://aptp.accenture.com/BuySell">\n      // Some More codes.\n</ns0:TradeMessage>';

    document.write(xml);

    xml = xml.replace(/<ns0:TradeMessage\sxmlns:ns0="http:\/\/aptp\.accenture\.com\/BuySell">[\S\s]*?<\/ns0:TradeMessage>/g, "null")

    document.write(xml);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you should not use regular expressions to modify XML (or HTML). Instead, use a parser that takes the XML and constructs a DOM tree from it, which you can then modify.  All modern browsers support the [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) object for this purpose.

That being said, here is a quick-and-dirty regular expression to do what you want in this specific case.  This will only work if there are no closing angle brackets (greater-than signs, `>`) inside the attributes of the `ns0:TradeMessage` tag.

```
xmlString = xmlString.replace(/<\/?ns0:TradeMessage[^>]*>/g, "");
```

Breakdown of the regex:

```
<                   // opening angle bracket
\/?                 // optionally, a slash (present only in closing tag)
ns0:TradeMessage    // tag name
[^>]*               // sequence of zero or more characters that are not closing angle brackets
>                   // closing angle bracket
```